# Get inner view size inside viewDidLoad IOS 10

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I made a demo project for my problem. I added a tableview inside UIViewController. I set tableview constraint like this image. When I want to get this bounds and frame, I received picture 2. How I get tableView size like inside viewDidAppear ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You don't! There is no layout information present in viewDidLoad, the application gets layed out afterwards.

Comment: in `-viewDidLoad` this information is not available.

Answer (score 2):

UIView has a frame property and since UITableView inherits from UIView you can just use tableView.frame to get its frame, and to get its width and height you can use tableView.frame.size.width and tableView.frame.size.height.

Please note that you will not get proper dimensions of your view in viewDidLoad but you will get proper width and height in viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear.

If you want the screen size you can always use UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height and UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width

Hope this helps.